# python apply function with df as input

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a function that uses 2 dataframes and a number as inputs. I want to apply that function to every row in a dataframe while using an input from that dataframe in the aforementioned function.

```
def function(df1, df2, number):

df3['result'] = df3['number'].apply(function, args=(df1, df2, df3['number']))
```

However I am getting **TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Rewrite your function as `function(number, df1,df2)` then call `df3['number'].apply(function, df1,df2)`.

Answer (score 0):

@Quang solutions is good, you can also explicitly use a lambda which might increase readability:

```
df3['result'] = df3['number'].apply(
    lambda s: function(df1, df2, s)
)
```

Comment: Neither solution works unfortunately, @Quang solution yields the same error, lamba solution gives ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1619, placement implies 1

Comment: A think this might be a problem on de definition of the funcion, as it only receives 0-dimension argument. Not series nor dataframes